# Collaborative Filtering, run time approach for large data

Tags: collaborative-filtering, recommendation-engine

I have a large data set. Almost 300,000 users and 30 million rows. What would be the best approach to handle user-user filtering at run time?

Iterating user by user, is very slow, during run time and even if done offline.

The data is in a mysql database right now.

Thanks.